# override the content-type being set in the req.header with node js?

Tags: node.js, express, http, post, content-type

I have a web service making a post request to an API and in the process, for some reason, the content-type value of the header is being overwritten from 'application/json' to 'text/html'. This is causing the POST request to fail since the API only accepts the content-type: 'application/json'. To overcome this I was going to make the web service touch a proxy web server that would implement the server-side code to modify the req.header value "content-type" back to 'application/json' and send the post request along with the req.body and req.headers to the API. I am trying to do this in node js (with express js). How do i override the req.header on the proxy node js server? I have tried playing with the accept content-type to only application/json but that did not do what i needed :(

Answer (score -1):

```
let request = require('request');

let proxyRequest = (data,headers)=>{
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'your-api-url',
  if (headers.hasOwnProperty('Content-Type')){
       delete headers['Content-Type']
    }
 
    headers['Content-Type']= 'application/json'

  body: data

};
    request(options, function (error, response) { 
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      console.log(response.body);
    });


};
```